# Is there any solution for unreadable Arabic characters in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, character-encoding, adobe, oracle9i

please I need help with PDF file that have Arabic characters ,it is old document exported from old version from oracle , when i open the document all characters are unreadable , I tried to add many Arabic fonts in windows fonts and also in adobe fonts, the same result still view unreadable,
can anyone help please.
Document properties:
Application:Oracle 9 i a s Report services
PDF producer: Oracle PDF Driver
PDF Version:1.4(Acrobat 5.x)
Thank you

Comment: Please share an example of those PDFs for analysis. While I have no experiences with Arabic PDF issues, other readers here surely do and might be able to identify the required font.

Comment: @mkl kindly find a sample of document in this link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTqdx1lywgwJ84KLH8JnYYCQvJ77hG23/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Look for "ArabicTransparent", "ArabicTransparent,Bold", "SimplifiedArabicFixed", "SimplifiedArabicFixed,Bold" Type1 fonts.